# pytorch, AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'Tensor'

Tags: python, python-3.5, centos7, torch, pytorch

I'm working with **Python 3.5.1** on a computer having **CentOS Linux 7.3.1611** (Core) operating system.

I'm trying to use **PyTorch** and I'm getting started with [this tutorial](https://github.com/mila-udem/welcome_tutorials/blob/master/pytorch/1.%20The%20Torch%20Tensor%20Library%20and%20Basic%20Operations.ipynb).

Unfortunately, the #4 line of the example creates troubles:

```
>>> torch.Tensor(5, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'Tensor'
```

I cannot understand this error... of course in Torch the 'torch' does have an attribute 'Tensor'. The same command works in Torch.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `>>> help(torch)` or `>>> torch` or `>>> dir(torch)`, etc. you have more information than us

Comment: Here's it: `Help on package torch:

NAME
    torch

PACKAGE CONTENTS


FILE
    (built-in)

(END)`

Comment: `>>> torch
<module 'torch' (namespace)>`

Comment: `>>> dir(torch);
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
`

Comment: Try to dive into your python folder and find the torch library to check what went wrong

Comment: uninstall pytorch completely and install again. otherwise finding the error will be tedious.

Comment: @WasiAhmad I tried and did not work...

Comment: @ManuelLagunas Thanks but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: How did you tried to install `PyTorch`?

Comment: @Rafael I used conda

Comment: What does `torch.__path__` give you?

Comment: @TarunLalwani It returns `'/home/davide/torch'`

Comment: Please rename that folder `/home/davide/torch` to something else and try again. It may be interfering with the original torch package

Comment: @DavideChicco.it what version of torch have you installed?  I am finding similar issues using version `0.4.0` where features in the pytorch tutorials do not exist in this version.

Comment: @Bill Unfortunately, I was unable to solve the problem. I will not edit the original Torch package, nor remove it. If you find a solution, please post it here. Thanks

Comment: @DavideChicco.it I was trying to find out what version of pytorch you had this problem with.

Answer (score 15):

The Python binary that you are running does not have `torch` installed. It *does* have a directory named `torch` on the module search path, and it is treated as a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/):

```
$ pwd
/some/path
$ python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch); print(torch.__path__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
$ mkdir torch
$ python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch); print(torch.__path__)'
<module 'torch' (namespace)>
_NamespacePath(['/some/path/torch'])
```

Any directory without a `__init__.py` file present in it, located on your module search path, will be treated as a namespace, provided *no other Python modules or packages by that name are found* anywhere else along the search path.

This means that if `torch` was installed for your Python binary, it doesn't matter if there is a local `torch` directory:

```
$ ls -ld torch/
drwxr-xr-x  2 mjpieters users  68 Nov 23 13:57 torch/
$ mkdir -p additional_path/torch/
$ touch additional_path/torch/__init__.py
$ PYTHONPATH="./additional_path" python3 -c 'import os.path as p, sys; print(*(t for t in (p.join(e, "torch") for e in sys.path) if p.exists(t)), sep="\n")'
torch
/some/path/additional_path/torch
$ PYTHONPATH="./additional_path" python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch); print(torch.__path__)'
<module 'torch' from '/some/path/additional_path/torch/__init__.py'>
['/some/path/additional_path/torch']
```

The above shows that `sys.path` lists the `torch` directory first, followed by `additional_path/torch`, but the latter is loaded as the `torch` module when you try to import it. That's because Python gives priority to top-level modules and packages before loading a namespace package.

You need to install torch correctly for your current Python binary, see the [project homepage](http://pytorch.org/); when using `pip` you may want to use the Python binary with the `-m` switch instead:

```
python3.5 -m pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.2.0.post3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
python3.5 -m pip install torchvision
```

So replace the `pip3` the homepage instructions use with `python3.5 -m pip`; `python3.5` can also be the full path to your Python binary.

Do use the correct `download.pytorch.org` URL for the latest version.

You don't have to move the directory aside, but if you do want to and don't know where it is located, use `print(torch.__path__)` as I've shown above.

Again, note that if you *do* have an `__init__.py` file in a local `torch` directory, it becomes a regular package and it'll mask packages installed by `pip` into the normal `site-packages` location. If you have such a package, or a local `torch.py` single-file module, you need to rename those. The diagnostic information looks different in that case:

```
$ pwd
/some/path
$ python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch); print(torch.__path__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
$ mkdir torch
$ touch torch/__init__.py  # make it a package
$ python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch); print(torch.__path__)'
<module 'torch' from '/some/path/torch/__init__.py'>
['/some/path/torch']
$ rm -rf torch/
$ touch torch.py           # make it a module
$ python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch); print(torch.__file__)'
<module 'torch' from '/some/path/torch.py'>
/some/path/torch.py
```

Note the differences; a namespace package, above, uses `<module 'name' (namespace)>`, while a regular package uses `)``, while a plain module uses``.

Such packages and modules (not namespace packages) are found first and stop the search. If the found package or module is not the one you wanted, you need to move them aside or rename them.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I followed all your steps but nothing changed. Additional ideas?

Comment: @DavideChicco it can you create a pastie or gist with your output, so we can diagnose what might be going wrong? Does `python3.5 -m pip freeze` list torch at all?

Comment: Here's the output of `python3.5 -m -pip freeze`: `python3.5 -m pip freeze
numexpr==2.6.1
numpy==1.11.1
olefile==0.44
pandas==0.18.1
Pillow==4.3.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.6.1
PyYAML==3.12
scikit-learn==0.17.1
scipy==0.17.1
six==1.10.0
tables==3.2.3.1
torch==0.2.0.post3
torchvision==0.1.9`

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: so `torch` is there as version `0.2.0.post3`. Does `python3.5 -c 'import torch'` still produce the traceback in your question?

Comment: `python3.5 -c 'import torch'` to works fine. Also `import torch` from the Python3.5 shell works fine. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: I thought I had already responded, sorry for the delay. I asked for the wrong thing, `import torch` clearly worked before. What does `python3.5 -c 'import torch; print(torch)` produce? Does `torch.Torch` still fail with an attribute error?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. `python3.5 -c 'import torch; print(torch)` prints nothing. `torch.Torch` prints/does nothing.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: that's.. **very** unexpected. `torch.Torch` is not a valid attribute (I meant to ask for `torch.Tensor`). Even the first one should produce output. I see I missed out a closing `'` quote, so perhaps the shell is waiting for more input. The correct commands are `python3.5 -c 'import torch; print(torch)'` and `python3.5 -c 'import torch; print(torch.Tensor)`. If the latter produces an attribute error, then the first one tells us what was imported instead of the expected package.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `python3.5 -c 'import torch; print(torch)'` and I got: `<module 'torch' from '/home/davide/torch/__init__.py'>`. I ran `python3.5 -c 'import torch; print(torch.Tensor)` and got `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'Tensor'`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: that's a change from before, you now have a `torch` package *in your homedirectory*. What is `/home/davide/torch/` and why is there a `__init__.py` file in it? It is now masking the versions installed by `pip`.

Comment: `/home/davide/torch/` is my normal install folder for Torch. I think my problems might come up because I have installed Torch years ago and now I'm trying to install PyTorch, and there might be some conflict. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: @DavideChicco.it rename or move that folder.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: You don't need to have Lua Torch installed to run PyTorch. Also, Python only adds `.` (the current working directory) to the Python path, so if you changed directories to somewhere else (`mkdir pytorch_workarea; cd pytorch_workarea`) then Python would also not try to import `torch` from the home directory.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: Last but not least, it is safe to rename the `torch` directory in your home directory. You can then edit the `. /home/davide/torch/bin/torch-activate` line in your `/home/davide/.bashrc` file to point  to the new directory name, and re-run the `./install.sh -s` in the Lua Torch directory to update any local paths.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue when installing the pytorch module within my notebook. I had to restart my Jupyter Notebook Kernel which resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the notebook is running with `python2`.
See the `metadata` section of the [notebook file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mila-udem/welcome_tutorials/master/pytorch/1.%20The%20Torch%20Tensor%20Library%20and%20Basic%20Operations.ipynb) (open in a text editor)

```
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 2",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python2"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 2
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
   "version": "2.7.13"
  }
 }
```

**FIX**
1. Ensure the `python3.5` kernel for ipython/jupyter is installed:
`python3.5 -m ipykernel install --name python3.5.1`

2. Run `jupyter notebook` and change kernel version in the notebook:
[image]

or hackily edit the `<notebook.ipynb>` directly (not recommended):

```
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3.5.1",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3.5.1"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.5.1"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Faced similar issue. 
Just install pytorch in new conda environment. It will work
You may have to install jupyter in new conda environment again, if you want to work on jupyter notebook.

Comment: this answer needs more detail. suggest you include your python version and OS version at the very least

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too, finally I found there is a "copy.py" in my directory, this name caused the chaos, I renamed the file, and problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same question, one .py works well and another report this error.
Try to run the following command:

```py
import torch
print(torch.__path__)
If (you get a wrong path): 
  then you know what you need to do.
Else if (even can not get the path printed): 
  just remove the temp file of your IDE（.idea or __pycache__）.
```

I do not know why, but it works for me. I hope it helps.