# Can't pip install torch

Tags: python, installation, pip, torch, stanza

I was trying to `pip install stanza` and got this message:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.3.0 (from stanza)
```

I then ran `pip install torch` and got the following (the website won't let me include too much code, so [here's the full error](https://onlinegdb.com/ryvI7IYzw))

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python37\python.exe' ... ...
  ...  ...
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    ... ...
    File "C:\Users\borka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-10i7vgad\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python37\python.exe' ... ...
       cwd: C:\Users\borka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-10i7vgad\torch
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for torch which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python37\python.exe' ... ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ... ...
      File "C:\Users\borka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-10i7vgad\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python37\python.exe' ... ... Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you have a Windows machine, so from [this official pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#mac-anaconda) website, you can build the command that the best for your requirements and system, try this

```
pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

And [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html), all of the `torch` packages are located, both Windows, MacOS, and Linux

Comment: It got installed, and so did stanza. But now when I try to load the 'en' model in stanza, I get an error saying `module 'torch' has no attribute 'tensor'`

Comment: @chocojunkie This is different problem. Please update your question or create another question.

Comment: @chocojunkie I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317141/pytorch-attributeerror-module-torch-has-no-attribute-tensor) question, please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same error and realized that Python 3.9 is not supported by Pytorch yet. I created another virtual environment with Python 3.7 and the installation worked.

Comment: this turned out to be true still in Nov 2021. in my case once i changed the interpreter to python 3.8, everything was okay