# PyTorch: module 'torch' has no attribute 'gradient'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

PyTorch seems to have a serious bug leading to the error message

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute [some torch function]
```

In my case, I try to use `torch.gradient` [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gradient.html).
I am using Python version `3.8.5` and tried the PyTorch Versions `1.6.0`, `1.7.0`, `1.7.1` , `1.8`, `1.9.0` for CPU. (The newest version has another bug for gradient [torch.gradient edge order](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/67919)).

There are several answers suggesting that I should install `torch` via pip, I should install `torchvision`, nothing worked. There is also the suggestion, that [the wrong torch folder is used as a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317141/pytorch-attributeerror-module-torch-has-no-attribute-tensor) which does not seem to be the case, since there is an `init`file when I run
`print(torch.__path__)`

So my question is:
**How to finally solve this problem?**

---

I tried to install it with the recommended pytorch.org version for conda, with anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch and with pypi.org/project/torch – nothing worked.

---

The `conda list torch` element gives

```
pytorch                   1.7.1               py3.8_cpu_0  [cpuonly]  pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
torchaudio                0.7.2                      py38    pytorch
torchvision               0.8.2                  py38_cpu  [cpuonly]  pytorch
```

Comment: How did you install PyTorch? With `conda`?

Comment: I tried to install it with the recommended https://pytorch.org/ version for conda, with https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch and with https://pypi.org/project/torch/

Comment: *"I tried"*, in the end what did you use to install PyTorch on your machine: pip or conda?

Comment: I used several environments for each versions. In one environment I used pip, in another one conda.

Comment: In your conda environment, can you do `conda list torch`?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it into the description now. Do you think the packages are overlapping?

Comment: Thank you, how are you loading your environment, i.e. executing your python script?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I let it run via a jupyter kernel in Visual Studio Code. Is that, what you ask?

Comment: Ok, can you check the version the kernel is running (`torch.__version__`). There might be a version mismatch between the version you see listed and the one you are actually running in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me. What I did was to create a new conda environment and reinstall PyTorch according to https://pytorch.org/